# Jenkins - push to deploy test step fails

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jenkins

I am following the instructions on [Push to deploy](https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy) to use Jenkins to test and deploy a Google App Engine app written in python and Flask.

the test is located in the root folder of the app in a file called `tests.py`

The command in the execute shell step is

```
nosetests tests.py
```

I get the following error and I am not sure how to troubleshoot this as I am fairly new to Jenkins.

```
Started by user User Name
Building remotely on cloud-dev-php in workspace /var/jenkins/workspace/CFC Melbourne production pipeline
 > git rev-parse --is-inside-work-tree # timeout=10
Fetching changes from the remote Git repository
 > git config remote.origin.url https://source.developers.google.com/p/cfc-melbourne-website/ # timeout=10
Fetching upstream changes from https://source.developers.google.com/p/cfc-melbourne-website/
 > git --version # timeout=10
using .gitcredentials to set credentials
 > git config --local credential.helper store --file=/tmp/git7069316934747655973.credentials # timeout=10
 > git -c core.askpass=true fetch --tags --progress https://source.developers.google.com/p/cfc-melbourne-website/ +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
 > git config --local --remove-section credential # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
 > git rev-parse refs/remotes/origin/origin/master^{commit} # timeout=10
Checking out Revision 3a8caffa38303b3ae4741aac83e6ac807077b5be (refs/remotes/origin/master)
 > git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
 > git checkout -f 3a8caffa38303b3ae4741aac83e6ac807077b5be
 > git rev-list 3a8caffa38303b3ae4741aac83e6ac807077b5be # timeout=10
[CFC Melbourne production pipeline] $ /bin/sh -xe /tmp/hudson3364335209750264714.sh
+ nosetests tests.py
/tmp/hudson3364335209750264714.sh: 2: /tmp/hudson3364335209750264714.sh: nosetests: not found
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't really a Jenkins problem — as the build output indicates, your shell script is failing because it cannot find the `nosetests` executable:

```
nosetests: not found
```

Have you made sure that [`nose` is installed](https://nose.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#installation-and-quick-start) on the `cloud-dev-php` Jenkins build machine?

Supposedly it should [already be installed](https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy#python) if you're using that push-to-deploy image — but as your build is running on the *PHP* build machine rather than the *Python* machine, perhaps that's not the case.
You should double-check that you've followed the [instructions](https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy#choose_the_tooling_environment) to ensure that your Python Jenkins job runs on a Python build machine.

If it *is* installed, perhaps it's not on the default `PATH`, in which case you can change the usage of `nosetests` to `/usr/local/bin/nosetests` (or whatever the path is).

Comment: Make sure you verify all that (the `PATH` specifically) for the `jenkins` user (default with Jenkins installation) not your own login

Comment: Thanks. I have configured the the appropriate Jenkins slave with restrictions and it worked.