# Jenkins -push to deploy failure on deploy stage to Google App Engine

Tags: python, git, google-app-engine, jenkins

This is a follow on question from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30123950/jenkins-push-to-deploy-test-step-fails).

So I managed to get the python tests to run. I have configured Jenkins using the push to deploy [guide](https://cloud.google.com/tools/repo/push-to-deploy) from Google

I am executing a shell command as follows:

```
gcloud --project=cfc-melbourne-website preview app deploy app.yaml
```

I get the following error

```
[workspace] $ /bin/sh -xe /opt/bitnami/apache-tomcat/temp/hudson678919665445088696.sh
+ gcloud --project=cfc-melbourne-website preview app deploy app.yaml
WARNING: The [application] field is specified in file [/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/CFC Melbourne production pipeline/workspace/app.yaml].  This field is not used by gcloud and should be removed.
WARNING: The [version] field is specified in file [/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/CFC Melbourne production pipeline/workspace/app.yaml].  This field is not used by gcloud and should be removed.
ERROR: The version [1] declared in [/opt/bitnami/apps/jenkins/jenkins_home/jobs/CFC Melbourne production pipeline/workspace/app.yaml] does not match the current gcloud version [20150509t012658].
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Errors occurred while parsing the App Engine app configuration.
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

Please help. Thanks.

Contents of app.yaml can be seen [here](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/b24a4167ad9779a15caa)

Comment: please show your app.yaml.

Comment: I have added it to the main post.

Comment: Try doing this "gcloud preview app deploy DIRECTORY --project cfc-melbourne-website" add directory name which contains yaml file.

Note to you. the application field in app.yaml file is deprecated and is not used by gcloud. Instead, make sure that your Google Developers Console project name is set correctly in gcloud config. reference from https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud-app

Answer (score 1):

So I figured it out. Just add the version and it works !!

```
gcloud --project=cfc-melbourne-website preview app deploy app.yaml --version=1
```